# Java MozSwing and charset

Tags: java, character-encoding, mozilla

i have integrated succesfully mozswing in my swing project, but i have a problem with the special chars "àèìòù" (italians).

this is my code:

```
public class CreatePanel2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(500, 600);
        MozillaPanel moz = new MozillaPanel(MozillaPanel.VisibilityMode.FORCED_HIDDEN, MozillaPanel.VisibilityMode.FORCED_HIDDEN);    
        frame.getContentPane().add(moz);
        frame.setVisible(true); 
        MozillaAutomation.blockingLoadHTML(moz, "à è ì ò ù", null); //$NON-NLS-1$
        Document document = moz.getDocument();
        try {
            DOMUtils.writeDOMToStream(document, System.out);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }        
    }

}
```

This is the console output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<html>
<head/>
<body>ÃƒÂ  ÃƒÂ¨ ÃƒÂ¬ ÃƒÂ² ÃƒÂ¹</body>
</html>
```

and this is a screenshot:

[image]

How i can change the charset in mozswing?

Please help, and thank you! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Solved!!

I have to set charset in a metatag:

```
MozillaAutomation.blockingLoadHTML(moz, "<html><head><meta http-equiv=Content-Type content='text/html; charset=utf-8' /></head><body>àò€</body></html>", null);
```